# How to explain derivative's Chain Rule

Tags: calculus

I've been wondering if is there an easy way to explain derivative's Chain Rule, since it's such a fundamental topic in Calculus and people struggle to understand the first time that they get in touch with the subject (like I did).

How would you explain it to your grandmother?

Thank you!

Comment: $$\dfrac{\mathrm dy }{\mathrm dx } = \dfrac{\mathrm dy }{\mathrm dz } \times \dfrac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dx }$$ Grandma, see how the $\mathrm dz$'s cancel out.

Comment: Hi @Ishfaaq can you produce a simple verbal explanation, without formulas?

Comment: Related questions include [Chain Rule Intuition](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62614/chain-rule-intuition). Do the answers there help?

Comment: The Usain Bolt analogy used there is really intuitive, thank you @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: Can't quite understand the downvote. This is a legitimate question related to teaching. @bru1987 the answer there by Mariano about linear approximations is also very enlightening.

Comment: Trying to describe it without formulae strikes me as silly project. In any case, you might a more receptive audience on http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's true @Ishfaaq, even though I think the Usain bolt analogy resonates better with teen students, it is a good explanation, intuitive also to explain. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not trying not to use formulae @SimonS, just use it as an introduction before the formulae begins. For example, the first sentences I could say to introduce the topic.

Answer (score 2):

My Grandmother was a Professor of Functional Analysis so I wouldn't even dare. 
However, if I did, I'd probably say if $f$ and $g$ are functions then the chain rule tells you how to write down the derivative of their *composition*.

That is; to evaluate $(f\circ g)'$ defined by $$(f\circ g)'=(f'\circ g)\cdot g'$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for the purpose of learning, not the proof, then take the example of $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(\sin(x))$. Take $\sin x=u$. Now, differentiate $\sin u$, which is $\cos u$. Now remember, you took a value of $u$, now, differentiate *that* value of $u$, which is again, $\sin x$, which comes out to be $\cos x$/ So multiply both, $$\cos(u)\dot\sin(x)$$ 
 $u=\sin(x)$ $$\cos(\sin(x))\sin(x)$$.

Comment: Hi @Aditya, thank you. I was thinking a verbal explanation, something that doesn't require formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a few gears put together in some mechanism. You have a knob on the first and the last one, so you can turn those individually. If you think of a gear as a function, what a gear does is it takes 'input' from the gear before it, and rotates according to it's own size. Something like $$\text{twist of the (n-1)th gear }\stackrel{\text{nth gear}}\mapsto \text{twist of the nth gear }.$$

So, let's say I twist the first gear by some angle $\mathrm d \theta_1$. How is this related to the angle the last gear will twist? Something like this:

$$\mathrm d\theta_n = \prod_i^n \text{(individual change of the i-th gear)}\times \mathrm d \theta_1$$

And this is the chain rule, on an example that works because the rate of change of a gear is just a ratio of the previous to this one. Which, again, encodes the fact that you can 'cancel out' the infinitesimals to get
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{d f}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$$
in a dumb but intuitive way.

Comment: Thank you for the sophisticated explanation @krvolok.

Comment: It's silly but it's a nice way to explain to yourself how come you have to multiply the derivatives of each function, where each derivative is with respect to the argument of the function!