# How is that differentiation of $\cos(\theta)$ possible?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I pondered upon this transformation in a book and have some confusion about it.
$$y =\cos(\theta) = \sin\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)$$$$dy = d\left(\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)\right)=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right) \times d(-\theta) = \cos\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right) \times (-d\theta)$$

---

$$\frac {dy}{d\theta}=-\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)=-\sin(\theta)$$

---

The main part I don't understand is:
$$dy = d\left(\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right)\right)=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\theta\right) \times d(-\theta)$$

This is (from what I can tell) an informal way to differentiate $\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: This is a very odd way of writing a corollary of the chain rule

Comment: It assumes that you know the derivative of $\sin$ and it uses the chain rule.

Comment: This is just the chain rule. If you draw the graphs of $\sin$ and $\cos$ you can see how the derivatives are related.

Comment: By the way, you can type `\cos` and `\sin` to get $\cos$ and $\sin$ (rather than $cos$ and $sin$, which respectively refer to the products $c \cdot o \cdot s$ and $s \cdot i \cdot n$). We definitely appreciate the effort to MathJax, though!

Comment: @BrianTung Oh, yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: @hash1: No worries! Just a tip, is all. Good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain rule says that if f(y) is a differentiable function of y and y(x) is a differentiable function of x, then $\frac{df}{dx}= \frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$.

In this example, $f(y)= \sin(y)$ and $y(x)= \frac{\pi}{2}- x$.  $\frac{df}{dy}= \cos(y)$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}= -1$.

So with $f(x)= \cos(x)= \sin(\pi- x)$ $\frac{df}{dx}= \frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}= \cos(y)(-1)= -\cos\left(\frac\pi2- x\right)= -\sin(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions boils down to the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), a fundamental aspect of elementary differentiation. If you are not familiar with it, check out [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62614/chain-rule-intuition) on the intuition of the chain rule.